# Azure SendGrid connected to create-react-app for UI

Tags: node.js, reactjs, azure, email, sendgrid

So I have my app created using `create-react-app` in Azure, but need to add ability to send mail once a Form is submitted. I know this cannot be done in my react app, but being away from backend work for a bit, I was trying to search for a tutorial or something online that could guide me and setting up some sort of `node.js` with sendgrid so that this UI can now process sending emails with my forms. Can any of you recommend some direction, tutorials, etc... to assist with this as I am not seeing things on the Sendgrid website for this.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Check the library [`sendgrid-nodejs`](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/tree/master/packages/mail) repo, which includes detailed examples for Node.js:

> ```
> const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
> sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
> const msg = {
>   to: 'test@example.com',
>   from: 'test@example.com',
>   subject: 'Sending with SendGrid is Fun',
>   text: 'and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js',
>   html: '<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js</strong>',
> };
> sgMail.send(msg);
> ```

For more complex use cases, please see [USE_CASES.md](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/blob/master/packages/mail/USE_CASES.md).